# Problems implementing Google Sheets API to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-sheets

I am trying to make a kotlin app that gets data from a google sheets through the sheets api. The problem of this is that many of the videos showing this are outdated and the documentation for the sheets API seemingly doesn't have the Android section that it used to have. Does anyone know if this is still possible? If so could anyone point me to a good resource to help me

I've already tried many outdated videos & the java section of the Sheets API Documentation, which have not worked for me